# ffmpeg timestamps on extracted frames wrong / extract frames a equal timestamps

Tags: bash, ffmpeg

I have a set of videos with different length, sizes, fps etc. and extract from each video exactly 60 frames as images, with timestamps put on each frame.

For this purpose I divide each videos length by 60 and use `fps=1/x` to extract the frames at even seconds from the video.

This works fine but the printed timestamps are slightly off.

This is the code I use (part of a bash script).

1. Compute intervals:

```sh
output_frame_count=60
video_duration=$(ffprobe -v error -show_entries format=duration -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 -i file.mp4)
capture_distance=$(bc <<< "scale=0; ($video_duration / $output_frame_count)")
```

2. Then run ffmpeg with the arguments

```sh
ffmpeg -i file.mp4 -vf "fps=1/$capture_distance,scale=-1:$height,drawtext=fontfile=/usr/...: text='%{pts\:gmtime\:0\:%H\\\\\:%M\\\\\:%S}: x=(w-tw)/2: y=h-(2*lh): fontcolor=white: box=1: boxcolor=0x00000000@1" frames%04d.png
```

I checked the images and all timestamps are wrong, compared to the original image from which they were extracted.

Does anyone has a more reliable way to extract exactly 60 frames from a video with correct timestamps printed on them?

Comment: Maybe you could share a video for which the results are wrong (probably using Dropbox or Google Drive) and say what exactly is wrong with the results vis-à-vis what you were expecting. Thank you.

Comment: I'll post a solution later. I used for the calculation now frames instead of time, which provides correct results.